# Каким образом можно разложить по столбцам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией, вот что получается (словарь со списком):

```
list_1 = [{
      "Object": "Лабуда",
      "subobject": "Лабуда",
      "Name": "Лабуда",
      "Ip": ".",
      "Status": "Лабуда",
      "Mac": Лабуда,
      "Sn": "Лабуда",
      "Client": [
         "Информация #4F6128"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Object": "Лабуда",
      "subobject": "Лабуда",
      "Name": "Лабуда",
      "Ip": "",
      "Status": "Лабуда",
      "Mac": "Лабуда",
      "Sn": "1 3 ",
      "Client": [
         "Информация #A00000"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Object": "Лабуда",
      "subobject": "Лабуда",
      "Name": "Лабуда",
      "Ip": "",
      "Status": "Лабуда",
      "Mac": "Лабуда",
      "Sn": " Лабуда",
      "Client": [
         "Информация #4F6128",
         "Информация #92D050"
      ]
   }]
```

И, вот мой код, который все раскидывает в xlsx (в excel):

```
import openpyxl
import json

with open('test.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)


book = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = book.active

sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 15
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = 33
sheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = 33
sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = 28
sheet.column_dimensions['F'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['G'].width = 36
sheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = 30
sheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = 25
sheet.column_dimensions['J'].width = 25
sheet.column_dimensions['K'].width = 15
sheet.column_dimensions['L'].width = 15

sheet['A1'] = 'Object'
sheet['B1'] = 'subobject'
sheet['C1'] = 'Name'
sheet['D1'] = 'Worker'
sheet['E1'] = 'Ip'
sheet['F1'] = 'Status'
sheet['G1'] = 'Mac'
sheet['H1'] = 'SN'
sheet['I1'] = '#4F6128'
sheet['J1'] = '#92D050'
sheet['K1'] = '#A00000'
sheet['L1'] = '#4f6128'

row = 2
for miners in data:
    sheet[row][0].value = miners['Object']
    sheet[row][1].value = miners['subobject']
    sheet[row][2].value = miners['Name']
    try:
     sheet[row][3].value = miners['Worker']
    except:
        pass
    sheet[row][4].value = miners['Ip']
    sheet[row][5].value = miners['Status']
    sheet[row][6].value = miners['Mac']
    sheet[row][7].value = miners.get('Sn')
    try:
        sheet[row][8].value = '  '.join(miners['Client'])
    except:
        pass
    #sheet[row][9].value = ?
    #sheet[row][10].value = ?
    #sheet[row][11].value = ?
    row += 1

book.save('file.xlsx')
book.close()
```

*В итоге, мне надо как-то раскидать значение у Client, в нем есть информация и значение цвета, в какой столбец надо засунуть. Их всего 4.*
Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, если нужно -  то конечно раскидайте. И цвет засуньте куда хотите.  Не можете понять в какой столбец? Так их всего четыре, суйте в какой вам больше нравиться. Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Я не знаю как это можно раскидать, что бы каждый столбец принимал свои значение( по нех цвету)

Comment: Приведите ваши попытки решить эту проблему. Что вам мешает записывать в одну из ячеек, причем значение второго индекса в sheet[row][....] выбирать в зависимости от прочитанного значения цвета?